# Convert String into JSON through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

String is :

```
AVG(Disk Usage,CPU USAGE,NETWORK USAGE,SUM(Shared Memory Usage,System Memory Usage))
```

Output Required :

```
{
   "operation": "AVG",
   "rules": [
     {
       "field": "Disk Usage"
     },
     {
       "field": "CPU Usage"
     },
     {
       "field": "Network Usage"
     },
     {
       "operation": "SUM",
       "rules": [
         {
           "field": "Shared Memory Usage"
         },
         {
           "field": "System Memory Usage"
         }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This string is template for all other input of strings? or in other wards, do want generic function for all kind of strings or only for this specific string?

Comment: its a basic template. that particular string is generated dynamically as per the requirement. Operations such as AVG, SUM, COUNT are identifiable. I am receiving Operations in a list as well as other metrics such as (disk usage, CPU usage) in a different list

Comment: could be there multiple nested operations like `AVG(... SUM(...), COUNT(...)` ?

Comment: yes multiple nested operations is possible. Seeking a generic solution for this. It would be of great help if you can provide solution for the same.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can you pls provide some logic code snippet. Really needed this one. I am not able to think what logic I need to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote the solution for your case using some regexp pattern, `RegExp.exec`, `String.split` and `Array.map` functions. 
I also added one more nested operator to process complex example.
Hope it will help ...

```
var str = "AVG(Disk Usage,CPU USAGE,NETWORK USAGE,SUM(Shared Memory Usage,System Memory Usage),COUNT(Processes,Services))",
    re = /(\w+?)\(([^()]+)(?=,\w+?\()|(?:,\))?(\w+?)\(([^)]+)/g, m, idx, 
    obj = {}, result = {};

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    idx = m.index;  // position of the current matched item in the initial input string
    m = m.filter((v) => v); // to get consecutive filled matched items
    obj = {'operation': m[1], 'rules' : m[2].split(",").map((v) => ({'field':v}))};
    if (idx === 0) { // the first function(operator) i.e. "AVG"
        result = obj;
    } else {
        result['rules'].push(obj);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "operation": "AVG",
    "rules": [
        {
            "field": "Disk Usage"
        },
        {
            "field": "CPU USAGE"
        },
        {
            "field": "NETWORK USAGE"
        },
        {
            "operation": "SUM",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "field": "Shared Memory Usage"
                },
                {
                    "field": "System Memory Usage"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "operation": "COUNT",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "field": "Processes"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Services"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the logic. It worked. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
JSON.parse(jsonObj); //javascript
```

You should do something like this:

```
var jsonObj = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Hi I am seeking a generic solution for this. As multi nested operations are possible. It would be great if you provide the generic solution for this

Comment: @JubinMehta, you have to use foreach

Comment: Still not able to finalize the logic for this. Can you pls provide some logic code snippet. Really needed this one. I even tried foreach but since it can be a nesting operation therefore not able to generate the logic for the same

Comment: Thanks a lot for the logic !

Comment: @JubinMehta, pls, check mark for my solution if it helped;) thanx